# How can I merge 2 bitmap layers in Sketch App?

Tags: sketch-app, bitmap

Is there a way (or a workaround) to merge 2 bitmap layers in Sketch?

I often use cutouts of print screens to start sketching out new interfaces and I would like to merge these into 1 bitmap afterI'm done with the sketching and ready for the 'real' work.

So far I just group and lock them, but this is not always wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can merge multiple layers into one bitmap by selecting the layers you want to merge together and going to:

**Layers > Flatten Selection to Bitmap**

Answer (score 1):

The one with **Layers>Flatten selection bitmap** is the best way of merging two layers (as already mentioned in the other answer).

But often times you will want a pattern to be merged rather than just two shapes.

To do that you can follow the steps below.

- Choose the bitmap/pattern/Groups of patterns, group them and export.
- Now fill the shape which you want with this exported image
- (You can fill the shape by clicking on **fill>choose the image option rather than color** (you will find 5 circular options, but by default color is selected, so change that to image and upload the image and done)